# Pivot table with case statement

Tags: t-sql, case

I have a table like so. I am trying to get it to pivot to be a singular record. The issue is that the transporter line number goes to like 231 for some records (bad public dataset). So my solution is to return the first transporter, 2-9 transporter, final transporter. However I am struggling to understand how to incorporate the max value to return into the query as I get the error of aggregate within an aggregate.

[image: Initial Table]

```
Select manifesttrackingnumber,
 Min(Case TRANSPORTERLINENUMBER When 1 Then concat(trim(TRANSPORTERNAME),' (',trim(TRANSPORTEREPAID),')') End) 'First Transporter',
 Min(Case TRANSPORTERLINENUMBER When 2 Then concat(trim(TRANSPORTERNAME),' (',trim(TRANSPORTEREPAID),')') End) 'Transporter 2',
 Min(Case TRANSPORTERLINENUMBER When 3 Then concat(trim(TRANSPORTERNAME),' (',trim(TRANSPORTEREPAID),')') End) 'Transporter 3',
 Min(Case TRANSPORTERLINENUMBER When 4 Then concat(trim(TRANSPORTERNAME),' (',trim(TRANSPORTEREPAID),')') End) 'Transporter 4',
 Min(Case TRANSPORTERLINENUMBER When 5 Then concat(trim(TRANSPORTERNAME),' (',trim(TRANSPORTEREPAID),')') End) 'Transporter 5',
 Min(Case TRANSPORTERLINENUMBER When 6 Then concat(trim(TRANSPORTERNAME),' (',trim(TRANSPORTEREPAID),')') End) 'Transporter 6',
 Min(Case TRANSPORTERLINENUMBER When 7 Then concat(trim(TRANSPORTERNAME),' (',trim(TRANSPORTEREPAID),')') End) 'Transporter 7',
 Min(Case TRANSPORTERLINENUMBER When 8 Then concat(trim(TRANSPORTERNAME),' (',trim(TRANSPORTEREPAID),')') End) 'Transporter 8',
 Min(Case TRANSPORTERLINENUMBER When 9 Then concat(trim(TRANSPORTERNAME),' (',trim(TRANSPORTEREPAID),')') End) 'Transporter 9',
 Max(Case TRANSPORTERLINENUMBER When max(transporterlinenumber) Then concat(trim(TRANSPORTERNAME),' (',trim(TRANSPORTEREPAID),')') End) 'Final Transporter'
   From TRANSPORTER
```

Answer (score 0):

Implemented a subquery to return the max number for each ID.